# Entity Framework Core - Cannot drop the index 'TableName.IX_TableName_ColumnName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: entity

I've tryied but I can't solve this by myself. It happens when I want to add composite key in my table using Entity Framework Core. Add-Migration passes but this error comes after Update-Database:

"Cannot drop the index 'TableName.IX_TableName_ColumnName', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: There was a Drop Index method in the last migration I added and after I deleted it everything worked fine. But is it ok to edit the migrations manually?

Comment: Why not? Probably snapshot has bad information about current database state and migration was generated incorrectly.